# Regex pattern for one or two numbers not part of a 4 number group

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to write a regex pattern which will be used in a Data Studio report (which uses [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)) to extract the first number between 1 and 13.

Here's an example of what I want:

```
8X/CS2 = 8
Experiment = no match
7Y/CS3 = 7 
7Y/CS2 = 7
2019-10T/Tk1 = 10
2019-7x/Pe4 = 7
2019-8x/Pe4 = 8
2019-12E/Tk-II = 12
2019-12D/Ps-4 = 12
```

I have established that `([1-9]|1[0123])` will extract numbers.

RE2 does not support negative lookbehind so I can't use that.

Comment: you don't need negative lookbehind.  you can just exclude it by not adding it to the capture group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex seems to be working:

```
(?:^|\D)(1[0123]|[1-9])(?:\D|$)
```

The number itself will be available in the first capture group.

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
(?:^|\D)         match either start of string or non digit character
(1[0123]|[1-9])  match 1-13
(?:\D|$)         match either end of string or non digit character
```

The idea is to match 1-13 which is surrounded by boundaries on both sides as defined as something which is not a number.  Note that with lookarounds, we could more easily write this:

```
(?<!\d)(1[0123]|[1-9])(?!\d)
```

However, since your flavor of regex does not support this, we have to use some other way.